# Path Extension shows while executing the Python File in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Program :

```py
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.workbook import workbook

df_excel = pd.read_excel("regions.xlsx")
df_csv = pd.read_csv("Names.csv")
df_txt = pd.read_csv("data.txt")

print(df_excel)
```

Output

```
PS C:\Users\user\Pandas_Project>  & 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.10.exe' 'c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.20.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '64322' '--' 'c:\Users\user\Pandas_Project\main.py'
Region  Units  Sales  Export
0  South     54    332     100
1  North     20    110      50
2   East     36    224      85
3   West     60    400     110
4   West     50    226      65
5  North     84    470     150
```

I request only below to shows not the path extension

```
Region  Units  Sales  Export
0  South     54    332     100
1  North     20    110      50
2   East     36    224      85
3   West     60    400     110
4   West     50    226      65
5  North     84    470     150
```

Comment: Give this a try: df_str = df_excel.to_string()
print(df_str)

Comment: first search SO, this is how VSC starts the debugger, if you don't want this use a task, and type the command you want, or type it yourself in the terminal or use a different tool to run Python, maybe IDLE

Answer (score 0):

You can change the "console" to "internalConsole" in your `launch.json`. Your launch.json will look like:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "internalConsole",
    }
  ]
```

[image]

Then your debug will be run in the **Debug Console** where will not show the path.

If you want to run python file without path, you can use [code-runner extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) and add the following codes to your `settings.json`:

```
"code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
"code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
```

In this way, you can click the **Run Code** button and it'll not show the path as well.

[image]